# Groupby output of my dataframe is some hexadecimals, but not values? why?

Tags: python, pandas

My dataframe has 192 columns: first column is time and second column value. These two columns belong to one particular field data. Third column is time and fourth column value and these two belong to another field. Like wise, I have data from 96 fields (datetime stamp and value) leading to 192 columns. This is two year data. Each day, a field will have some 200 samples. Same is the case for all 96 fields.

1. I am trying to find the maximum value on each day for a given field. I want to store this maximum value along a column named after that field and along with the day in as data frame called max_data. This can be used again at later. Similarly, I will replicate for all other fileds and store their values in max_data.
2. I want to plot the each day maximum of a field that is max_data dataframe?

My code:

```
.
for i,j in zip(modules_pmpp_df.columns[::2],modules_pmpp_df.columns[1::2]):
    modules_pmpp_df[i] = pd.to_datetime(modules_pmpp_df[i])
    print(modules_pmpp_df.groupby(modules_pmpp_df[i].dt.strftime('%B'))[j].max)
```

Present output is:

```
<bound method GroupBy.max of <pandas.core.groupby.groupby.SeriesGroupBy object at 0x0000000004E3F518>>
<bound method GroupBy.max of <pandas.core.groupby.groupby.SeriesGroupBy object at 0x0000000008020C88>>
<bound method GroupBy.max of <pandas.core.groupby.groupby.SeriesGroupBy object at 0x00000000560AA668>>
.
.
```

A modified code as per @jezrael gives following output:

```
print(modules_pmpp_df.groupby(modules_pmpp_df[i].dt.strftime('%B'))[j].max())
```

Output is:

```
TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'float'
```

A modified code as per @U9-Forward gives following output:

```
print(modules_pmpp_df.groupby(modules_pmpp_df[i].dt.strftime('%B'))[j].max(axis=1))
```

Output is:

```
TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'float'
```

Comment: You forget `()` after last `max`, so need `print(modules_pmpp_df.groupby(modules_pmpp_df[i].dt.strftime('%B'))[j].max())`

Comment: @jezrael, I tried that. It gave error. Please see my modified response in my above question.

Comment: @Msquare How about: `print(modules_pmpp_df.groupby(modules_pmpp_df[i].dt.strftime('%B'))[j].max(axis=1))`

Comment: @U9-Forward, I just now tried this code you mentioned. This gave error as `TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'float'`

Comment: @Msquare I think you should check the data type in your dataframe. Maybe you really have string and float objects in the same column? If you can present peace of data, I can try to help you.